# GridView.count: ListTiles are not disappearing above my List

Tags: flutter, gridview

I'm using the GridView.count widget which works alright. But when I'm scrolling down you can see the tiles going behind my other stuff above my GridView part. You can see it through the little Spaces. I want them to disappear when they go above their starting point.

Also please give me any advice on other parts of my code (3 weeks into Flutter).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itLVZ.png)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[200],
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text("Stromberg Soundboard"),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
              height: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/bernd.jpeg'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
            const SeasonsAndJokes(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 30,
          width: double.infinity,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5),
          color: Colors.green[100],
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                iconSize: 32,
                disabledColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: lastSeason,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_left_sharp),
              ),
              Text(
                seasonsText[indexische],
                style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textScaleFactor: 1.3,
              ),
              IconButton(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                iconSize: 32,
                onPressed: nextSeason,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right_sharp),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 380,
          child: GridView.count(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, left: 5),
            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 3,
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < titelSeasonOne.length; i++)
                ListTile(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white38),
                  ),
                  trailing: const Icon(
                    Icons.volume_up_sharp,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                  tileColor: Colors.green[200],
                  textColor: Colors.black87,
                  title: Text(
                    titelSeasonOne[i],
                    textScaleFactor: 1,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    final player = AudioCache();
                    player.play(audioSeasonOne[i]);
                  },
                ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add image on the behavior and the one you want to achieve also

Comment: @ArbiterChil yes sure. I have 2 links at the end of the code. One ist the starting picture where you can see the grey area between the picture and the box where it says "Staffel 1". But when I scroll (see other picture) you can see how the tile fills the gap with green. So the tiles go basically over the whole screen even behind the picture. But I want it to disappear behind the "Staffel 1" Container.

Comment: you mean like you don't want the gridview overlap on the back of the other widget?

Comment: @ArbiterChil exactly!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.